# JRebel relative path for deployed war

Tags: xml, jboss, relative-path, jrebel

I've recently started using JRebel with Eclipse and Jboss and its working perfectly fine for me. Its deploying changed files to

> D:/Workspace/Project/build/classes

as I've mentioned the same in `rebel.xml`. However I want to change the path relative to the recently deployed war in `tmp` folder inside the Jboss server. Is there a way I can do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case,

```
D:/Workspace/Project/build/classes
```

Is the directory where your IDE compiles the classes to. **rebel.xml** just specifies for JRebel where to load those classes from.

To use the relative path you can define a placeholder:

```
${workspace.path}/Project/build/classes
```

And then you can expand the placeholder by defining the placeholder value via VM arguments:

```
-Dworkspace.path=D:/Workspace
```

Unfortunately there's no way to specify the real relative path, a-la **../build/classes**

My question would rather be why do you want to specify the path to JBoss's tmp folder?

Comment: Just as I specified that, whenever I redeploy my project, it goes to a new folder created inside `tmp`.

Comment: When you deploy with JRebel it actually loads all the resources from the locations specified in rebel.xml. That is why I fail to see the purpose of tmp/ in this case.

Comment: Yeah true, I know that, it was just a question out of curiosity. Anyways thanks for responding :)